# Multiline paste (ctrl-r) into ex or search|replace ^M with \r

Tags: linux, unix, vim, paste, ex

When I'm yanking few lines and pasting it to command-line every new line is `^M` instead `\r`. For example if I copy next two lines in visual mode (with command `Vjy`):

```
line1
line2
```

and paste it in command-line (search) mode with command `/<c-r>"` I get:

```
/line1^Mline2
```

But I expected: `/line1\rline2`

What i want to do is to highlight pasted string what is helpful when I'm pasting block of code.
I know i can select it with

```
`[v`]
```

but i want to only highlight it, and anyway it can by useful to by able to paste multiline code into ex for substitute or other funny things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copying the next paragraph in visual mode:

```
line1
line2
line3
```

and pasting it in command-line  (with `<c-r>"`) should give `line1^Mline2^Mline3^M`. If you want this text to be `line1\rline2\rline3\r` you could define the following function and map:

```
function! Substitute()                                                          
    silent! let g:p=substitute(@", "\\n", "\\\\r", "g")                         
    call feedkeys(":", 'n')                                                     
endfunction                                                                     
nnoremap <silent> : :call Substitute()<cr>
```

The command `let g:p=substitute(@", "\\n", "\\\\r", "g")` will find every `^M` in the unnamed register (`:help quotequote`), replace it with `\r`, and store output string in `p`. To paste the contents of `p` in command-line use `<c-r>=p`.

Comment: Working like a harm. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to "cast" register contents into a certain (characterwise / linewise / blockwise) mode so often, I wrote the [UnconditionalPaste plugin](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3355) for it. It provides `gcp`, `glp`, etc. alternatives to the built-in paste commands that force a certain mode; some variants are also available as *command-line mode mappings*.

The `<C-r><C-q>` mapping queries for a separator string, then inserts the contents of a register characterwise, with each line delimited by it. So, to achieve your desired result, that would be `<C-r><C-q>"\\r<CR>`.

Note: If you want to search fo the multiline text, you'd actually have to use `\n` instead of `\r`.